# How to use i right in a for loop?

Tags: python

I have 3 lists and I need to calculate for each i the product of first list i, second list i and third list len-(i+1).

I tried to make a for loop which will do it for each i and I wrote this

```
i = 0
for i in list:
    smh=list1[i]*list2[i]*list3[len-(i+1)]
    print(smh)
    i = i + 1
```

But it says in the second line "'type' object is not iterable"
How can I make it work?

Comment: 1. Python's loops are more like forEach, you get the element not the index. 2. You're iterating over the list class not a list instance.

Comment: Your first sentence appears to be missing a word after "the product of".

Comment: You can use the `zip` built in function to iterate over multiple lists at the same time

Comment: also `list3[len-(i+1)]` ... `len` is a function, you can do `len(list3)` ... but for this case in Python you can use negative index to count from end of the list like `list3[0-i]` (assuming `i` was an index number, which it's not in your code currently)

Comment: (1) you haven’t defined `list`. The `list` you’re referring to is a Python native type and makes no sense on this context, and why you’re getting that particular error message. (2) try a loop like `for I in xrange(blah)` where blah is the max value + 1 you want `I` to take during the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you would need to get a little fancy and use the `zip()` function to properly iterate over all the members of the list.

here is some information on it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-iterate-multiple-lists-simultaneously/

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [3,4]
list3 = [4,5]
for (a, b, c) in zip(list1, list2, reversed(list3)):
   smh = a*b*c
   print(smh)
```

Output: 15, 32.

Comment: check the index of the last item from list3, the OP wants the third list to be reversed.

Comment: Thanks for that, I jumped the gun! Ill change the answer!

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this, using the [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function and the builtin [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
for x in zip(list1,list2,reversed(list3)):
    smh = reduce(operator.mul,x)
    print(smh)
```

i tested my idea with this code:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [5,6,7,8]
list3 = [9,10,11,12]

for x in zip(list1,list2,reversed(list3)):
    smh = reduce(operator.mul,x)
    print(' * '.join(map(str,x)),"=",smh)
```

and it produces this output:

```
1 * 5 * 12 = 60
2 * 6 * 11 = 132
3 * 7 * 10 = 210
4 * 8 * 9 = 288
```